# Camera App like screen rotation and navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, screen-rotation

I would like to replicate exact behavior of native Camera App (including its navigation to gallery and back) where when device is rotated, UI controls rotate in place instead of whole screen rotating. I was able to replicate the rotation behavior by locking screen in portrait mode and handling device rotation notifications manually like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification*)note {
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

  UIInterfaceOrientation newOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
  switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
      newOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
      break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
      newOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
      break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
      newOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
      break;

    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
      newOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
      break;

    default:
      newOrientation = self.currentOrientation;
      break;
  }

  if (newOrientation == self.currentOrientation) {
    return;
  }
  self.currentOrientation = newOrientation;
  [self rotateInterfaceToOrientation:self.currentOrientation];
}

- (void)rotateInterfaceToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
  double rotationAngle = 0;
  switch (orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: rotationAngle = M_PI; break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: rotationAngle = M_PI_2; break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: rotationAngle = -M_PI_2; break;
    default: rotationAngle = 0; break;
  }

  CGFloat angle = (float)rotationAngle;
  self.defaultTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);

  ... manual animation by setting transform
}
```

This works well and behaves exactly as I need.

My problems are related to the fact, that the screen according to app is still in portrait.

Whole application supports both portrait and landscape mode. When I navigate to different screen and back, transition is broken since it is transitioning from landscape view to portrait view. Just before the transition animation starts, the former landscape view changes layout to portrait (altho it is weirdly stretched). Video from simulator: http://gfycat.com/DeafeningGaseousBrant. You can see the layout changes when transition starts. It is much more apparent on device as you can see the screen whole time. It might be worth mentioning I'm using custom transition manager to make screens go correct direction when navigating (this might explain why views move like they move but it has no effect on the problematic behavior).

Also when I display prompt with keyboard or UIAlertView their orientations are wrong. Again simulator: http://gfycat.com/SelfreliantPointedEwe.

Is there any way to specify from viewcontroller that view is currently in portrait or landscape orientation? Or is there way to have screen rotate manually without using autolayouts resizing/layouting?

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is applied by rotating and reshaping a view.  If you apply the inverse rotation and reshaping to your view it will appear to not rotate.

By reshaping, I mean swapping the width and height.

When rotating to landscape, apply a transform that rotates your view (-)90 degrees and manually swap the width and height of the bounds.  Your view will no longer appear to rotate, but the interface orientation will not be affected.  Also rotate any subviews by the opposite angle and move them to match the reshaped bounds.

Comment: I read that solution in other question, but I can't believe that is the correct way. When using autolayout, without complicated editing of constraints based on device orientation, it would be impossible to achieve the wanted effect.

One of the things is, when you rotate device to landscape left, trigger button is on right side. When you rotate it to the right landscape, it is on left side. This simply can't be done with autolayout alone. There must be some other magic happening.

Answer (score 1):

> where when device is rotated, UI controls rotate in place instead of whole screen rotating

Actually, that's not what happens. The app *does* rotate - but the elements *also* rotate, and they use `animateAlongside` so their rotation is synchronized with the app's rotation. You can't tell that the app is rotating, because there's no status bar to indicate this.

Comment: Well, the way Camera.app actually does it is a bit more complicated that that because they also rotate stuff when rotation lock is on.

Comment: @FilipRadelic I didn't notice that. That is actually really nice catch. So it seems they really don't rotate the screen to landscape. But how would they have the navigation working when transitioning to and from gallery?

Comment: @Montas I wasn't implying they don't rotate the screen. They definitely do when rotation lock is off (you can confirm that because control center and notification center work properly), it's just that it gets a bit more complex with rotation lock on.

Comment: @FilipRadelic They do rotate the controls, but when you open gallery, it opens in portrait mode. That is why I think they don't actually rotate the screen, and only use some transition magic to make it look like the screen is rotated.

By the way, with my solution, when rotation is locked, my controls don't rotate.

Comment: @matt "The app does rotate" how do you know this for sure?

Comment: @Alfa I don't know what you mean by "solve". It is easy to make a view that stays the same way up regardless of how the app is rotated, and my answer tells you how.

Comment: Hi @matt, I'm also doing the same, like rotating the view. Since this topic dates back to 2015 and I was just willing to know any newer solutions available. Maybe I framed it wrong. should hv not used 'solve`.

Comment: @Alfa OK but your comment is directed to _me_ and _my_ answer. (You didn't at-sign some other user.) So I'm replying that as far as I'm concerned nothing is changed. I still use this technique to keep an individual view pointing "up" (from the ground) no matter how the app is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple's library that opens from preview is not a navigation opened view controller, that's the modal opened view controller, it's even opens from preview. And only when you touch the button "all photos", only in this moment loads initial photo app, with real navigation bar...
(I checked that in iOS 9)